# Searching, $_POST variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, http-post

I have this code block in html for inputting the search.

```
<?php echo form_open('bookstore/_searchbook'); ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
    <label for="searchid">Search:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
    <input type="text" size="15" name="searchid" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
    <label for="searchtype">Type:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
    <select>
        <option value="book_id">Id</option>
        <option value="book_author">Author</option>
        <option value="book_name">Title</option>
    </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

And i have this on my controller,

```
public function booksearch()
{
  if($_POST['submit'])
  {
    $col= $this->input->post('searchtype', TRUE);
    $val= $this->input->post('searchval', TRUE);

    $data['book'] = $this->books_model->showbook($col,$val);
    $this->load->view('showbooks',$data);
  }
}
```

and this would be my model

```
public function showbook($col, $searchid)
{
        $this->db->select()->from('books')->where(array($col=>$searchid));
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->first_row('array');
}
```

Further info on my view,

I have this to print the results of my search.

```
<table cellpadding='5'>
<th>Book ID</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Released Year</th>
<th>ISBN</th>

<?php
if(isset($books)) : foreach($books as $book) :  
?>      
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_author'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_year'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_isbn'] ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    endforeach;
?>

<?php
else :
?>
<h5>No records</h5>
<?php
endif;
?>
</table>
```

It returns nothing so all i see is no records. Someone direct me to the thing i did wrong.

Comment: you open the form with `bookstore/_searchbook` and your function name is `booksearch`... is that intended?

Answer (score 1):

- Your form's action (view) is `_searchbook` while your controller function is `booksearch`
- Your submit input needs a `name` attribute
- in the controller function you have `$data['book']` while in your view (in the foreach loop) you reference that variable as `$books`
- Model: you need to select at least something; e.g. `$this->db->select('*')->from('books')->where(array($col=>$searchid));` instead of  `$this->db->select()`
- Model: I think you need `return $query->result_array();` instead of `$query->first_row('array')`

Answer (score 0):

Because your submit button has not got any `name` attribute. Instead of `if($_POST['submit'])` write `$this->input->post(null)`

Comment: Silly me, forgot the name attribute..

small things you dont expect to be the problem :(

Comment: Happie to help! Accept the answer if it helped you. :D

Comment: I also forgot to add, $this->load->view('showbooks',$data); on my controller so after the processing it links me back to my view and prints it.. hmm

Comment: Could you help me though?

it shows no records for my controller. I will update the one above so you can examine.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding global $_POST; to the top of your function. In php all variables used(declaired) in a function will be private unless you tell it otherwise by adding it to the global statement in the function.

```
public function booksearch()
{
      global $_POST;

if($_POST['submit'])
    {
    $col= $this->input->post('searchtype', TRUE);
    $val= $this->input->post('searchval', TRUE);

    return $data['book'] = $this->books_model->showbook($col,$val);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just updated my post above, that issue was already taken care of, i was just lacking the name attribute although that could be another way of doing it.

Anyways if you dont mind looking at it again.