# Fetch array result and row manipulation

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, rows

This will be my last question.

I am getting no rows as an result and i dont know what im doing wrong, plus i want to return multiple rows,

like in mysql where i can just use the argument like so i can return multiple rows and it would be a helpful query for searches as most searches are not accurately written or many. for example, i want to search a book from author john but john has 5 books and if i use first_row it would only return the first book and there might be a chance that the one im looking for would be at the 2nd or 3rd or 4th or 5th row.

Im new to ci, ive read a guide wherein i can use num_rows() but im not sure how to use it yet as ive not seen an example. Ive searched but to my disappointment, i found nothing that satisfies my needs.

Here is my html:

```
<?php echo form_open('bookstore/booksearch'); ?>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                    <label for="searchid">Search:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                    <input type="text" size="15" name="searchval" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                    <label for="searchtype">Type:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                    <select name="searchtype">
                                        <option value="book_id">Id</option>
                                        <option value="book_author">Author</option>
                                        <option value="book_name">Title</option>
                                    </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <?php echo form_close(); ?>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>

<table cellpadding='5'>
<th>Book ID</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Released Year</th>
<th>ISBN</th>

<?php
if(isset($books)) : foreach($books as $book) :  
?>      
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_author'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_year'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_isbn'] ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    endforeach;
?>

<?php
else :
?>
<h5>No records</h5>
<?php
endif;
?>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
public function booksearch()
    {
    if($_POST['submit'])
        {
        $col= $this->input->post('searchtype');
        $val= $this->input->post('searchval');

        $data['book'] = $this->books_model->showbook($col,$val);

        }
        $this->load->view('showbooks',$data);
    }
```

and my model:

```
public function showbook($col, $searchid)
{
        $this->db->select()->from('books')->where(array($col=>$searchid));
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->first_row('array');
}
```

I have posted a question earlier but with similar codes, I resolved it since i only missed the name attribute, small things you dont expect to be the problems can really waste your time. I Hope i didnt miss anything this time or it would be a shame on me if it happened twice. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Please refer to my answer given in your previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18082800/989234

Comment: FYI: you can ommit `select()`, please watch some http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
public function showbook($col, $searchid)
{
    $this->db->select()->from('books')->where(array($col=>$searchid));
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->first_row('array');
}
```

To:

```
public function showbook($col, $searchid)
{
    $this->db->select()->from('books')->where(array($col=>$searchid));
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: @user1891608 yes its returns all the results as an array which met with where condition.